# Thymeleaf th style

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying Thymeleaf (Spring Boot 4 and Thymeleaf 2.x) at my application but had a parsing error for this:

```
th:style="'background-image: url('+@̣{css/nema/neder-e.png}+');'"
```

Which point I miss?

Comment: Why to down vote? Could write any reasonable thing for it?

Comment: aren't you missing quotes around the url? the actual value of the url would need quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time, but here's the solution for those who have this problem in the future :

```
th:style="'background-image: url(your-image-path);'"
```

You don't need do add something, juste replace *your-image-path*.

**Exemple :**

```
th:style="'background-image: url(/images/image.jpg);'"
```

*images* is located at *resoureces/static* directory of Spring boot

Answer (score 0):

You have some weird characters between @ and { in your expression.  I don't know what they are (CCA3 in hex?), but the expression itself is valid once they are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
th:style="'background-image:url(' + @{'/css/nema/neder-e.png' + ');'"
```